# How to display message instead of NULL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am returning a query with names, courses and course codes, but where the course code is null i would like to display "NOT ENROLLED".
Could I do this by using a 'default'?
The select statement is coming from a VIEW would this make any difference.

```
CREATE VIEW STUDENT_LIST
(studentname, dateofbirth, coursecode)
AS 
SELECT COURSECODE, STUDENTNAME, DATEOFBIRTH
FROM STUDENT;

SELECT STUDENTNAME, DATEOFBIRTH, NVL(COURSECODE,"NOT_ENROLLED")
FROM STUDENT_LIST;
```

I get the reply NOT ENROLLED invalid identifier... I have tried without quotes 
I am using oracle.

Comment: Please provide more detail; for example, the select statement of interest would help.

Comment: And also which DBMS you're using. As @user983064 points out, different implementations have different null-coalescing functions.

Comment: What form of SQL are you using? sql-server / mysql?

Comment: What technology?  Are we talking about a direct query into SQL- if so, what type of SQL (MS Sql, MySql, whatever).  Is this some other kind of code (.NET, Java)?  There are several ways to handle this requirement, depending on your environment.

Comment: Starting with Oracle 8i you can use COALESCE instead of NVL, it's ANSI standard. Either one will work if you use single quotes, not double quotes, as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ORACLE has `NVL()`

SQL Server has `ISNULL()`

MySQL has `IFNULL()`

All of the above and PostgreSQL support `COALESCE()`.

So,

```
SELECT STUDENTNAME, 
       DATEOFBIRTH, 
       NVL(COURSECODE,'NOT_ENROLLED') 
FROM STUDENT_LIST;
```

or

```
SELECT STUDENTNAME, 
       DATEOFBIRTH, 
       COALESCE(COURSECODE,'NOT_ENROLLED') 
FROM STUDENT_LIST;
```

in Oracle.

Comment: Everytime I run the SELECT DATEOFBIRTH, COURSECODE, STUDENTNAME THE FIELDS IN THE TABLE ALL SWAP ROUND, dateofbirth is over names, coursecode is over dates, studentname is over codes.

Comment: @StudentRik That sounds odd, do you mean they are showing in your results in a different order than specified in your select?

Comment: can I drop the view table just like a normal table and try again?

Comment: @StudentRik Yep, except the syntax should be drop view ... instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT STUDENTNAME, DATEOFBIRTH, NVL(COURSECODE,"NOT_ENROLLED") FROM STUDENT_LIST;
```

> I get the reply NOT ENROLLED invalid identifier... I have tried
>   without quotes I am using oracle.

This is because you are using double quotes around NOT_ENROLLED.  In Oracle, you use single quotes around string literals.  Double quotes delimit identifiers that may have embedded spaces, so Oracle thinks NOT_ENROLLED is an identifier, not a string literal.

Use this:

```
    SELECT STUDENTNAME, DATEOFBIRTH, NVL(COURSECODE,'NOT_ENROLLED') FROM STUDENT_LIST;
```

Comment: OK thank you , but the column names dont match the columns when I swap the order of the select statement all the columns swap round as well (lol) I am trying to copy the order in which I started the view.

Answer (score 1):

Use nvl. Different implementations may vary, e.g. for MySQL you want ifnull.

Comment: Yes I thought about that. Thanks will try.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mySql, then yes! you can set a default value in place for NULL. And whenever a value will be none that value will be saved in database.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid NOT ENROLLED invalid identifier reply you should replace double quote by single quote:

replace:

```
SELECT STUDENTNAME, DATEOFBIRTH, NVL(COURSECODE,"NOT_ENROLLED")
FROM STUDENT_LIST;
```

by:

```
SELECT STUDENTNAME, DATEOFBIRTH, NVL(COURSECODE,'NOT_ENROLLED')
FROM STUDENT_LIST;
```

For Oracle double quotes are for columns or tables identifiers (for example that contains a space: "total items")

Answer (score 0):

One aspect of the problem not covered here is that we have only considered a general scenario of entering a text "display message" in a char field in a table.

If it were say a different number field like for example the DOB... in that case we convert use to_char and save the field otherwise we would be given  an error for invalid input

```
SELECT e.studentname, NVL(TO_CHAR(e.dateofbirth),'PLS Contact admin to update'), NVL(e.COURSECODE,'NOT_ENROLLED')
FROM STUDENT_LIST e;
```

This would save the text to the number field which otherwise would have resulted in an error.